# Calling EJB from servlet

Tags: servlets, jboss, ejb, jndi, lookup

I used JBOSS Develper Studio 8, JBOS server 7.1 based on jre 1.7 I have one J2EE project (which is name Dnevnik) with ejb (DnenvikEJB) and web projects (DnevnikWEB). I want to call ejb from servlet via jndi lookup. The name of EJB is FasadaPrvi and his remote interface is FasadaPrviRemote. I have problem with all of this code variants:

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
FasadaPrvi fasadaPrvi = (FasadaPrvi)context.lookup("java:comp/env/FasadaPrvi");

InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
FasadaPrvi fasadaPrvi = (FasadaPrvi)context.lookup("java:app/DnevnikEJB/FasadaPrvi");

InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
FasadaPrvi fasadaPrvi = (FasadaPrvi)context.lookup("java:global/DnevnikEJB/FasadaPrvi");

InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
FasadaPrvi fasadaPrvi = (FasadaPrvi)context.lookup("java:global/Dnevnik/DnevnikEJB/FasadaPrvi!sr.co.FasadaPrviRemote");
```

Does anybody know where is the problem!?

Answer (score 0):

From the Jboss-wiki: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JNDI+Reference 
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
// lookup the bean     Foo
beanRemoteInterface = (Foo) ctx.lookup("myapp/myejbmodule/FooBean!org.myapp.ejb.Foo");
String bar = beanRemoteInterface.sayBar();
```

and:

```
ejb:myapp/myejbjar/MyEjbName!com.test.MyRemoteInterface
ejb:myapp/myejbjar/MyStatefulName!comp.test.MyStatefulRemoteInterface?stateful
```

Also, during deployment of EJBs, Jboss shows you information with which JNDI-names your beans would be visible.

```
09:25:07,852 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named RegistrationService in deployment unit subdeployment "MY_EJB-15.99.00.war" of deployment "MY_EAR-15.00.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/MY_EAR-15.00/MY_EJB-15.00/RegistrationService!foo.RegistrationService
    java:app/MY_EJB-15.00/RegistrationService!foo.RegistrationService
    java:module/RegistrationService!foo.RegistrationService
    java:global/MY_EAR-15.00/MY_EJB-15.00/RegistrationService
    java:app/MY_EJB-15.00/RegistrationService
    java:module/RegistrationService
```